# Stream descriptor loss in fopen + stream _dup

Tags: c, winapi, stream, fopen, dup

I have the following code example (in windows):

```
int fd = _dup(fileno(stdout));
freopen("tmp","w",stdout);

printf("1111");
close(stdout);

char buf[100];

FILE *fp;   
fp = fopen("tmp","r");//in this line fd turns to be 0
if(NULL == fp) return -1;
if(fgets(buf,100 , fp) != NULL );
else return -1
fclose(fp);
```

I need the value of fd for the futher use.How can I read from file without losing the `fd` value?

Comment: There is no way the indicated line can affect the value of fd. You must have an error somewhere else in your code.

Comment: @ Klas Lindbäck - no.this is exactly the code.I debug it and see that the fd value is 3 until indicated line

Comment: Can't be. `fgets(buf,100 , fp) != NULL );` doesn't even compile. I tried it in Linux, and after correcting the syntax error the value of `fd` was 3 when the program ended.

Comment: Klas Lindbäck - sory it was a typo .In the question is wrote that the problem is regarding windows

Comment: @Yakov And now? C is C, and stdlib is stdlib. Makes no difference if Windows or Linux.

Comment: I saw that it was in windows, but that should not matter. Maybe the debugger is flawed? Have you tried printing the value of fd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bet that either buf is declared smaller than 100 or the fgets call is in fact with a number larger than 100.